# Expected identifier with pointers

Tags: c, identifier

So, I'm trying to put an item in my dynamic array, but I keep getting this error "expected identifier".

```
void Lista_Inicia(TLista *lista) {
    lista->item = (TItem *) malloc(100 * sizeof(TItem));
    lista->tamanho=100;
    lista->utilizado=0;
};

void Lista_Insere(TLista *lista, char palavra[]) {
    if(lista->tamanho==lista->utilizado){
        printf("Erro, não há espaço para inserção\n");
        return;
    }

    TItem* itemAux=malloc(sizeof(TItem));
    itemAux->quantidade=malloc(sizeof(int));
    itemAux->quantidade=1;
    itemAux->palavra=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(palavra)+1);
    strcpy(itemAux->palavra,palavra);
    lista->*item+(lista->utilizado)=itemAux; // <---Expected identifier here
    lista->utilizado++;
    printf("%d", lista->utilizado);
}
```

Instead of this code I already tried these ones too:

```
lista->item+(lista->utilizado)=itemAux; 
lista->*item[lista->utilizado]=itemAux; 
lista->item[lista->utilizado]=itemAux;
```

The structs I'm using:

```
typedef struct Item {
    char* palavra;
    int quantidade;
} TItem;

typedef struct Lista {
    TItem* item;
    int tamanho;
    int utilizado;
} TLista;
```

Comment: `lista->*item` isn't valid C. Simple typographic error.

Comment: `lista->item+(lista->utilizado)=itemAux; `? `lista->item+(lista->utilizado)` doesn't look like an lvalue to me.

Comment: this line: lista->*item+(lista->utilizado)=itemAux; might better be written as: lista+(lista->utilizado)->item=itemAux;

Comment: compile with `-Wall --pedantic`, because this: `itemAux->quantidade=malloc(sizeof(int));` should have your compiler shouting at you: assigning a pointer to an `int` member... that's just wrong, especially considering you're leaking the memory: `itemAux->quantidade=1;`, and at no point are you free-ing `itemAux`...

Answer (score 0):

`lista->*item` is invalid syntax. It looks like what you want to do is:

```
lista->item[lista->utilizado]=itemAux;
```

But the `item` field in your `lista` struct only has a pointer to a `TItem` (`TItem *`) but you are treating it like an array of pointers to `TItems` (`TItem **`). Try updating your `Lista` struct and the `Lista_Inicia` method as follows:

```
typedef struct Lista 
    TItem **item;
    int tamanho;
    int utilizado;
} TLista;

void Lista_Inicia(TLista *lista) {
    lista->item = (TItem **)malloc(100 * sizeof(TItem *));
    lista->tamanho=100;
    lista->utilizado=0;
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to access the other positions from lista->item.

Comment: Then `lista->item[lista->utilizado]=itemAux;` looks like what you want. What error do you get when you use it?

Comment: "error: assigning to 'TItem' (aka 'struct Item') from incompatible type 'TItem *' (aka 'struct Item *')"; deference with *"

Comment: I think I've figured out what you're trying to do. Have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already allocated 100 elements of type TItem in your list. So you need not to allocate memory for each new item. You simply have to use a free element in the allocated array.

The function can look like

```
void Lista_Insere( TLista *lista, char palavra[] )
{
    if ( lista->tamanho == lista->utilizado + 1 )
    {
        printf("Erro, não há espaço para inserção\n");
        return;
    }

    lista->item[lista->utilizado].quantidade = 1;
    lista->item[lista->utilizado].palavra = malloc( strlen( palavra ) + 1 );
    strcpy( lista->item[lista->utilizado].palavra, palavra );

    lista->utilizado++;

    printf("%d", lista->utilizado);
}
```

Or you may rewrite the function the following way using a temporary variable

```
void Lista_Insere( TLista *lista, char palavra[] )
{
    if ( lista->tamanho == lista->utilizado + 1 )
    {
        printf("Erro, não há espaço para inserção\n");
        return;
    }

    TItem itemAux;

    itemAux.quantidade = 1;
    itemAux.palavra = malloc( strlen( palavra ) + 1 );
    strcpy( itemAux.palavra, palavra );

    lista->item[lista->utilizado++] = itemAux;

    printf("%d", lista->utilizado);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Bruno Salerno Rocha  I rewrite my post. So see it again.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
TItem itemAux;
itemAux.quantidade=1;
itemAux.palavra=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(palavra)+1));
strcpy(itemAux.palavra, palavra);
lista->item[lista.utilizado]=itemAux;
lista->utilizado++;
printf("%d", lista->utilizado);
```

Comment: Can you indicate which part of the OP's code ought to be changed?

Comment: @DavidFaber from `TItem* itemAux=malloc(sizeof(TItem));` to `printf("%d", lista->utilizado);`